# ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import from a sub package in python

Tags: python-3.x, import, modulenotfounderror

I have the following layout:

```
└── folder_1
    └── __init__.py
    └── level_1.py
    └── folder_2
        └── __init__.py
        └── level_2.py
└── test
    └── __init__.py
    └── test_in.py
└── test_out.py
└── setup.py
```

And in my **setup.py** I specify `packages=["folder_1", "test"]`

In the **test_out.py** file I can import from **level_1.py** and **level_2.py** with no problem, but for some reason in the **test_in.py** file I can only import from **level_1.py**. If I try to import from **level_2.py** I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder_1.folder_2'
```

I also get errors if I try to do the import in the ****init**.py** from folder_1.
I'm running this on a jupyter lab and can't find a way to make this work. Is there a way to fix this without using the PYTHONPATH or things like that?

**EDIT:**

Just found out that if I add `folder_1.folder_2` to the content of packages in **setup.py** it works, however I'm not sure if this is the correct way to fix this?